# React.createElement type is invalid [DIFFERENT ERROR FROM OTHER SIMILAR POSTS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack, react-dom

My dilemma: everything compiles correctly and the django server runs well; however, the developer tools reveal the same errors. **NOTE: There are other similar posts on stack overflow and github; however, I have read through all of them and tried each of the suggested answers, to no avail!** Here is a screenshot of my error:

[image: Screenshot of error]

My project is a react/django project, so I currently have a file called "DataGetching.js" that pulls info from the api that I am trying to display on the screen by calling this component in my App.js. I am trying to do this while also implementing a navbar in App.js to try and get a feel for interaction between api and react components, as I grow as a developer. Here are my App.js, webpack, index.js, index.html, DataFetching.js, my file structure, and package.json.

**File Structure:**
[image: File Structure]

**App.js:**

```
import './index.css';
import { ReactComponent as BellIcon } from './icons/bell.svg';
import { ReactComponent as MessengerIcon } from './icons/messenger.svg';
import { ReactComponent as CaretIcon } from './icons/caret.svg';
import { ReactComponent as PlusIcon } from './icons/plus.svg';
import { ReactComponent as CogIcon } from './icons/cog.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ChevronIcon } from './icons/chevron.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ArrowIcon } from './icons/arrow.svg';
import { ReactComponent as BoltIcon } from './icons/bolt.svg';
import DataFetching from "../DataFetching";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DataFetching />
      <Navbar>
        <NavItem icon={<PlusIcon />} />
        <NavItem icon={<BellIcon />} />
        <NavItem icon={<MessengerIcon />} />
        <NavItem icon={<CaretIcon />}>
          <DropdownMenu></DropdownMenu>
        </NavItem>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}


function Navbar(props) {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <ul className="navbar-nav">{props.children}</ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

function NavItem(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <li className="nav-item">
      <a href="#" className="icon-button" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        {props.icon}
      </a>

      {open && props.children}
    </li>
  );
}

function DropdownMenu() {
  const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState('main');
  const [menuHeight, setMenuHeight] = useState(null);
  const dropdownRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMenuHeight(dropdownRef.current?.firstChild.offsetHeight)
  }, [])

  function calcHeight(el) {
    const height = el.offsetHeight;
    setMenuHeight(height);
  }

  function DropdownItem(props) {
    return (
      <a href="#" className="menu-item" onClick={() => props.goToMenu && setActiveMenu(props.goToMenu)}>
        <span className="icon-button">{props.leftIcon}</span>
        {props.children}
        <span className="icon-right">{props.rightIcon}</span>
      </a>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="dropdown" style={{ height: menuHeight }} ref={dropdownRef}>

      <CSSTransition
        in={activeMenu === 'main'}
        timeout={500}
        classNames="menu-primary"
        unmountOnExit
        onEnter={calcHeight}>
        <div className="menu">
          <DropdownItem>My Profile</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem
            leftIcon={<CogIcon />}
            rightIcon={<ChevronIcon />}
            goToMenu="settings">
            Settings
          </DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem
            leftIcon=""
            rightIcon={<ChevronIcon />}
            goToMenu="animals">
            Animals
          </DropdownItem>

        </div>
      </CSSTransition>

      <CSSTransition
        in={activeMenu === 'settings'}
        timeout={500}
        classNames="menu-secondary"
        unmountOnExit
        onEnter={calcHeight}>
        <div className="menu">
          <DropdownItem goToMenu="main" leftIcon={<ArrowIcon />}>
            <h2>My Tutorial</h2>
          </DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem leftIcon={<BoltIcon />}>HTML</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem leftIcon={<BoltIcon />}>CSS</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem leftIcon={<BoltIcon />}>JavaScript</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem leftIcon={<BoltIcon />}>Awesome!</DropdownItem>
        </div>
      </CSSTransition>

      <CSSTransition
        in={activeMenu === 'animals'}
        timeout={500}
        classNames="menu-secondary"
        unmountOnExit
        onEnter={calcHeight}>
        <div className="menu">
          <DropdownItem goToMenu="main" leftIcon={<ArrowIcon />}>
            <h2>Animals</h2>
          </DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem leftIcon="">Kangaroo</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem leftIcon="">Frog</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem leftIcon="">Horse?</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem leftIcon="">Hedgehog</DropdownItem>
        </div>
      </CSSTransition>
    </div>
  );
}




export default App;
```

**Webpack**

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'svg-url-loader',
              options: {
              limit: 10000,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ]
    }
  };
```

**DataFetching.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function DataFetching() {
    const [leads, setLeads] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("api/lead")
            .then(res =>{
                console.log(res)
                setLeads(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    leads.map(lead => <li key={lead.id}>{lead.name} says {lead.message}</li>)
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DataFetching
```

**index.js**

```
import App from "./App";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import React from "react";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root">
      <!-- React will load here -->
  </div>
  {% load static %}
  <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --entry ./src/index.js --output-path ./static/frontend",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --entry ./src/index.js --output-path ./static/frontend",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.31.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried building your code using a create-react-app project and couldn't reproduce the error. Possibly the error is related to your dependencies, which are different.

Comment: Locate the problem by removing elements in the App render one by one until the error disappears.

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Thanks for the suggestion. I've narrowed it down to my NavItems, which still confuses me terribly, but I'm going to create a new post now that the error is narrowed down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be changed. Changed the import line for each svg to
`import BellIcon from './icons/bell.svg';`

Then, in the webpack, change to:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
              // name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ]
    }
  };
```

In the package.json, need to add `"bootstrap-icons": "^1.4.1",`

Finally, in .babelrc, add a plugin:

`"plugins": [ "inline-react-svg" ]`